# How to remove products from wishlist?

Tags: javascript

Can you please tell me how to remove a product from wishlist?

I wrote a function that adds a product to favorites, for the button itself I change the class after adding, but there are 2 problems:

- going to the wishlist section when clicking on the button with the class "delete product" the function does not work
- after clicking on "add to wishlist", the class for the button is replaced by "already added", but when the page is refreshed, the "already added" class is overwritten and the already added product can be added to wishlist again.

I would be grateful for any information.

```js
function wishlistNewSt() {
  // Retrieve wishlist items from sessionStorage
  let wishlistItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('wishlistItems')) || [];

  // Add to wishlist
  let cardBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist_btn_st');
  let cardBox = document.querySelector('.wishlist_new_box');

  for (let i = 0; i < cardBtns.length; i++) {
    cardBtns[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (cardBtns[i].classList.contains('btn_added_to_wishlist')) {
        alert('allready added');
      } else {
        let item = cardBtns[i].parentElement;
        cardBtns[i].classList.remove('wishlist_btn_st');
        cardBtns[i].classList.add('btn_added_to_wishlist');
        let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
        cardBox.appendChild(clone);

        // Add the item to the wishlistItems array
        wishlistItems.push(clone.innerHTML);

        // Store the updated wishlistItems in sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('wishlistItems', JSON.stringify(wishlistItems));
      }
    });
  }

  // Remove from wishlist
let cardBoxItems = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist_new_box .product');
for (let i = 0; i < cardBoxItems.length; i++) {
  let btnRemove = cardBoxItems[i].querySelector('.btn_added_to_wishlist');
  if (btnRemove) {
    btnRemove.addEventListener('click', () => {
      cardBoxItems[i].remove();
      
      // Find the index of the item in the wishlistItems array
      let itemIndex = wishlistItems.findIndex(item => item === cardBoxItems[i].innerHTML);
      
      // Remove the item from the wishlistItems array
      if (itemIndex !== -1) {
        wishlistItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      }

      // Update the stored wishlistItems in sessionStorage
      sessionStorage.setItem('wishlistItems',
      JSON.stringify(wishlistItems));

      // Reassign the event listener to the updated button elements
      wishlistNewSt();
    });
  }
}

  // Load wishlist items from sessionStorage
  for (let i = 0; i < wishlistItems.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement('li');
    item.className = "pif-has-gallery product type-product";
    
    item.innerHTML = wishlistItems[i];
    cardBox.appendChild(item);
  }

  // Add class to buttons of products already in wishlist
  let wishlistButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.wishlist_btn_st');
  for (let i = 0; i < wishlistButtons.length; i++) {
    let item = wishlistButtons[i].parentElement;
    if (wishlistItems.includes(item.innerHTML)) {
      wishlistButtons[i].classList.add('btn_added_to_wishlist');
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  wishlistNewSt();
});
```

```css
.product {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.wishlist_btn_st {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.btn_added_to_wishlist {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
}
.wishlist_new_box {
  margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <li class="product post-95">
    <h3>Product_01</h3>
    <div class="wishlist_btn_st">+</div>
  </li>

  <li class="product post-96">
    <h3>Product_01</h3>
    <div class="wishlist_btn_st">+</div>
  </li>

  <li class="product post-97">
    <h3>Product_01</h3>
    <div class="wishlist_btn_st">+</div>
  </li>

  <div class="wishlist_new_box"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The main problem is that you are doing so many things at the same time, searching for elements, searching for class names, it's just a bit messy. You could start by simplifying the code. I would create a separate function for: `1 - loading wishlist items, 2 - display wishlist items, 3 - set an item as favorite, 4 - unset an item as favorite, 5 - save all items`. This way you can test functionality one by one and find your bugs much easier.